# G++ aborts compilation with no error message when file contains large array initializer

Tags: c++, gcc, mingw, initializer

I'm using Code::Blocks (v20.03) with MinGW64 g++ compiler (Windows 11), `g++ --version` shows (first line):

`g++.exe (MinGW-W64 x86_64-ucrt-posix-seh, built by Brecht Sanders) 12.2.0`

When trying to compile file that contains large two-dimensional array initializer - like this:

```
#define ROW { { 0.0,  0.0 }, {  1.0,  1.0 }, {  2.0,  2.0 }, {  3.0,  3.0 }, {  4.0,  4.0 }, \
    {  5.0,  5.0 }, {  6.0,  6.0 }, {  7.0,  7.0 }, {  8.0,  8.0 }, {  9.0,  9.0 } }
#define ROW8 ROW, ROW, ROW, ROW, ROW, ROW, ROW, ROW
#define ROW64 ROW8, ROW8, ROW8, ROW8, ROW8, ROW8, ROW8, ROW8
#define ROW512 ROW64, ROW64, ROW64, ROW64, ROW64, ROW64, ROW64, ROW64
#define ROW4096 ROW512, ROW512, ROW512, ROW512, ROW512, ROW512, ROW512, ROW512

template <typename T>
class cplx_t {
public:
  T m_re;
  T m_im;

    cplx_t() : m_re(), m_im() {
    }
      
    cplx_t(const T& re, const T& im) : m_re(re), m_im(im) {
    }
    
};

cplx_t<double> test_arr[2048][10] = {
    ROW512, ROW512, ROW512, ROW512
};

int main() {
}
```

using command:

`g++ ./test_large_init.cpp --verbose`

no output file is generated - console dump:

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\mingw\tools\install\mingw64\bin\g++.exe
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=c:/programdata/chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/lto-wrapper.exe
OFFLOAD_TARGET_NAMES=nvptx-none
Target: x86_64-w64-mingw32
Configured with: ../configure --prefix=/r/winlibs64-11.3.0ucrt/2604.gcc/inst_gcc-12.2.0/share/gcc --build=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --host=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --enable-offload-targets=nvptx-none --with-pkgversion='MinGW-W64 x86_64-ucrt-posix-seh, built by Brecht Sanders' --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --enable-threads=posix --disable-sjlj-exceptions --disable-libunwind-exceptions --disable-serial-configure --disable-bootstrap --enable-host-shared --enable-plugin --disable-default-ssp --disable-rpath --disable-libstdcxx-debug --disable-version-specific-runtime-libs --with-stabs --disable-symvers --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,lto,objc,obj-c++,jit --disable-gold --disable-nls --disable-stage1-checking --disable-win32-registry --disable-multilib --enable-ld --enable-libquadmath --enable-libada --enable-libssp --enable-libstdcxx --enable-lto --enable-fully-dynamic-string --enable-libgomp --enable-graphite --enable-mingw-wildcard --enable-libstdcxx-time --disable-libstdcxx-pch --with-mpc=/e/Prog/winlibs64-11.3.0ucrt/custombuilt --with-mpfr=/e/Prog/winlibs64-11.3.0ucrt/custombuilt --with-gmp=/e/Prog/winlibs64-11.3.0ucrt/custombuilt --with-isl=/e/Prog/winlibs64-11.3.0ucrt/custombuilt --enable-libstdcxx-backtrace --enable-install-libiberty --enable-__cxa_atexit --without-included-gettext --with-diagnostics-color=auto --enable-clocale=generic --with-libiconv --with-system-zlib --with-build-sysroot=/r/winlibs64-11.3.0ucrt/2604.gcc/gcc-12.2.0/build_mingw/mingw-w64 CFLAGS='-I/e/Prog/winlibs64-11.3.0ucrt/custombuilt/include/libdl-win32 -D__USE_MINGW_ACCESS' CXXFLAGS=-D__USE_MINGW_ACCESS LDFLAGS='-Wl,--disable-nxcompat -Wl,--disable-high-entropy-va -Wl,--disable-dynamicbase'
Thread model: posix
Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib zstd
gcc version 12.2.0 (MinGW-W64 x86_64-ucrt-posix-seh, built by Brecht Sanders)
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64' '-dumpdir' 'a-'
 c:/programdata/chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/cc1plus.exe -quiet -v -iprefix c:\programdata\chocolatey\lib\mingw\tools\install\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/ -D_REENTRANT ./test_large_init.cpp -quiet -dumpdir a- -dumpbase test_large_init.cpp -dumpbase-ext .cpp -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -version -o C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\ccv3X4Fb.s
GNU C++17 (MinGW-W64 x86_64-ucrt-posix-seh, built by Brecht Sanders) version 12.2.0 (x86_64-w64-mingw32)
        compiled by GNU C version 12.2.0, GMP version 6.2.1, MPFR version 4.1.0, MPC version 1.2.1, isl version UNKNOWN-GMP

GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
ignoring duplicate directory "c:/programdata/chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../include/c++/12.2.0"
ignoring duplicate directory "c:/programdata/chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../include/c++/12.2.0/x86_64-w64-mingw32"
ignoring duplicate directory "c:/programdata/chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../include/c++/12.2.0/backward"
ignoring duplicate directory "c:/programdata/chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "R:/winlibs64-11.3.0ucrt/2604.gcc/inst_gcc-12.2.0/share/gcc/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/r/winlibs64-11.3.0ucrt/2604.gcc/inst_gcc-12.2.0/share/gcc/include"
ignoring duplicate directory "c:/programdata/chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/include-fixed"
ignoring duplicate directory "c:/programdata/chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/mingw/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 c:\programdata\chocolatey\lib\mingw\tools\install\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../include/c++/12.2.0
 c:\programdata\chocolatey\lib\mingw\tools\install\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../include/c++/12.2.0/x86_64-w64-mingw32
 c:\programdata\chocolatey\lib\mingw\tools\install\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../include/c++/12.2.0/backward
 c:\programdata\chocolatey\lib\mingw\tools\install\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/include
 c:\programdata\chocolatey\lib\mingw\tools\install\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../include
 c:\programdata\chocolatey\lib\mingw\tools\install\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/include-fixed
 c:\programdata\chocolatey\lib\mingw\tools\install\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/include
End of search list.
GNU C++17 (MinGW-W64 x86_64-ucrt-posix-seh, built by Brecht Sanders) version 12.2.0 (x86_64-w64-mingw32)
        compiled by GNU C version 12.2.0, GMP version 6.2.1, MPFR version 4.1.0, MPC version 1.2.1, isl version UNKNOWN-GMP

GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
Compiler executable checksum: 16512d3bcd6e7fc30e988209e0d6f609
```

But when i remove initialization:

```
#define ROW { { 0.0,  0.0 }, {  1.0,  1.0 }, {  2.0,  2.0 }, {  3.0,  3.0 }, {  4.0,  4.0 }, \
    {  5.0,  5.0 }, {  6.0,  6.0 }, {  7.0,  7.0 }, {  8.0,  8.0 }, {  9.0,  9.0 } }
#define ROW8 ROW, ROW, ROW, ROW, ROW, ROW, ROW, ROW
#define ROW64 ROW8, ROW8, ROW8, ROW8, ROW8, ROW8, ROW8, ROW8
#define ROW512 ROW64, ROW64, ROW64, ROW64, ROW64, ROW64, ROW64, ROW64
#define ROW4096 ROW512, ROW512, ROW512, ROW512, ROW512, ROW512, ROW512, ROW512

template <typename T>
class cplx_t {
public:
  T m_re;
  T m_im;

    cplx_t() : m_re(), m_im() {
    }
      
    cplx_t(const T& re, const T& im) : m_re(re), m_im(im) {
    }
    
};

cplx_t<double> test_arr[2048][10];

int main() {
}
```

GCC generates output file properly - console dump:

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\mingw\tools\install\mingw64\bin\g++.exe
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=c:/programdata/chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/lto-wrapper.exe
OFFLOAD_TARGET_NAMES=nvptx-none
Target: x86_64-w64-mingw32
Configured with: ../configure --prefix=/r/winlibs64-11.3.0ucrt/2604.gcc/inst_gcc-12.2.0/share/gcc --build=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --host=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --enable-offload-targets=nvptx-none --with-pkgversion='MinGW-W64 x86_64-ucrt-posix-seh, built by Brecht Sanders' --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --enable-threads=posix --disable-sjlj-exceptions --disable-libunwind-exceptions --disable-serial-configure --disable-bootstrap --enable-host-shared --enable-plugin --disable-default-ssp --disable-rpath --disable-libstdcxx-debug --disable-version-specific-runtime-libs --with-stabs --disable-symvers --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,lto,objc,obj-c++,jit --disable-gold --disable-nls --disable-stage1-checking --disable-win32-registry --disable-multilib --enable-ld --enable-libquadmath --enable-libada --enable-libssp --enable-libstdcxx --enable-lto --enable-fully-dynamic-string --enable-libgomp --enable-graphite --enable-mingw-wildcard --enable-libstdcxx-time --disable-libstdcxx-pch --with-mpc=/e/Prog/winlibs64-11.3.0ucrt/custombuilt --with-mpfr=/e/Prog/winlibs64-11.3.0ucrt/custombuilt --with-gmp=/e/Prog/winlibs64-11.3.0ucrt/custombuilt --with-isl=/e/Prog/winlibs64-11.3.0ucrt/custombuilt --enable-libstdcxx-backtrace --enable-install-libiberty --enable-__cxa_atexit --without-included-gettext --with-diagnostics-color=auto --enable-clocale=generic --with-libiconv --with-system-zlib --with-build-sysroot=/r/winlibs64-11.3.0ucrt/2604.gcc/gcc-12.2.0/build_mingw/mingw-w64 CFLAGS='-I/e/Prog/winlibs64-11.3.0ucrt/custombuilt/include/libdl-win32 -D__USE_MINGW_ACCESS' CXXFLAGS=-D__USE_MINGW_ACCESS LDFLAGS='-Wl,--disable-nxcompat -Wl,--disable-high-entropy-va -Wl,--disable-dynamicbase'
Thread model: posix
Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib zstd
gcc version 12.2.0 (MinGW-W64 x86_64-ucrt-posix-seh, built by Brecht Sanders)
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64' '-dumpdir' 'a-'
 c:/programdata/chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/cc1plus.exe -quiet -v -iprefix c:\programdata\chocolatey\lib\mingw\tools\install\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/ -D_REENTRANT ./test_large_init.cpp -quiet -dumpdir a- -dumpbase test_large_init.cpp -dumpbase-ext .cpp -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -version -o C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\cczLmXyT.s
GNU C++17 (MinGW-W64 x86_64-ucrt-posix-seh, built by Brecht Sanders) version 12.2.0 (x86_64-w64-mingw32)
        compiled by GNU C version 12.2.0, GMP version 6.2.1, MPFR version 4.1.0, MPC version 1.2.1, isl version UNKNOWN-GMP

GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
ignoring duplicate directory "c:/programdata/chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../include/c++/12.2.0"
ignoring duplicate directory "c:/programdata/chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../include/c++/12.2.0/x86_64-w64-mingw32"
ignoring duplicate directory "c:/programdata/chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../include/c++/12.2.0/backward"
ignoring duplicate directory "c:/programdata/chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "R:/winlibs64-11.3.0ucrt/2604.gcc/inst_gcc-12.2.0/share/gcc/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/r/winlibs64-11.3.0ucrt/2604.gcc/inst_gcc-12.2.0/share/gcc/include"
ignoring duplicate directory "c:/programdata/chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/include-fixed"
ignoring duplicate directory "c:/programdata/chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/mingw/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 c:\programdata\chocolatey\lib\mingw\tools\install\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../include/c++/12.2.0
 c:\programdata\chocolatey\lib\mingw\tools\install\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../include/c++/12.2.0/x86_64-w64-mingw32
 c:\programdata\chocolatey\lib\mingw\tools\install\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../include/c++/12.2.0/backward
 c:\programdata\chocolatey\lib\mingw\tools\install\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/include
 c:\programdata\chocolatey\lib\mingw\tools\install\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../include
 c:\programdata\chocolatey\lib\mingw\tools\install\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/include-fixed
 c:\programdata\chocolatey\lib\mingw\tools\install\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/include
End of search list.
GNU C++17 (MinGW-W64 x86_64-ucrt-posix-seh, built by Brecht Sanders) version 12.2.0 (x86_64-w64-mingw32)
        compiled by GNU C version 12.2.0, GMP version 6.2.1, MPFR version 4.1.0, MPC version 1.2.1, isl version UNKNOWN-GMP

GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
Compiler executable checksum: 16512d3bcd6e7fc30e988209e0d6f609
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64' '-dumpdir' 'a-'
 c:/programdata/chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/as.exe -v -o C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\ccbZLACV.o C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\cczLmXyT.s
GNU assembler version 2.39 (x86_64-w64-mingw32) using BFD version (Binutils for MinGW-W64 x86_64, built by Brecht Sanders) 2.39
COMPILER_PATH=c:/programdata/chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/;c:/programdata/chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/bin/../libexec/gcc/;c:/programdata/chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/
LIBRARY_PATH=c:/programdata/chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/;c:/programdata/chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/;c:/programdata/chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/;c:/programdata/chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../lib/;c:/programdata/chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/;c:/programdata/chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64' '-dumpdir' 'a.'
 c:/programdata/chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/collect2.exe -plugin c:/programdata/chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/liblto_plugin.dll -plugin-opt=c:/programdata/chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/lto-wrapper.exe -plugin-opt=-fresolution=C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\ccNqe6C1.res -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmingw32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmoldname -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmingwex -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmsvcrt -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lkernel32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lpthread -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-ladvapi32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lshell32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-luser32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lkernel32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmingw32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmoldname -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmingwex -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmsvcrt -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lkernel32 -m i386pep -Bdynamic c:/programdata/chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/crt2.o c:/programdata/chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/crtbegin.o -Lc:/programdata/chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0 -Lc:/programdata/chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc -Lc:/programdata/chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib -Lc:/programdata/chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../lib -Lc:/programdata/chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib -Lc:/programdata/chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../.. C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\ccbZLACV.o -lstdc++ -lmingw32 -lgcc_s -lgcc -lmoldname -lmingwex -lmsvcrt -lkernel32 -lpthread -ladvapi32 -lshell32 -luser32 -lkernel32 -lmingw32 -lgcc_s -lgcc -lmoldname -lmingwex -lmsvcrt -lkernel32 c:/programdata/chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/crtend.o
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64' '-dumpdir' 'a.'
```

Moreover - if i replace **cplx_t** template with **std::complex** code can be compiled even with initializer:

```
#include <complex>

#define ROW { { 0.0,  0.0 }, {  1.0,  1.0 }, {  2.0,  2.0 }, {  3.0,  3.0 }, {  4.0,  4.0 }, \
    {  5.0,  5.0 }, {  6.0,  6.0 }, {  7.0,  7.0 }, {  8.0,  8.0 }, {  9.0,  9.0 } }
#define ROW8 ROW, ROW, ROW, ROW, ROW, ROW, ROW, ROW
#define ROW64 ROW8, ROW8, ROW8, ROW8, ROW8, ROW8, ROW8, ROW8
#define ROW512 ROW64, ROW64, ROW64, ROW64, ROW64, ROW64, ROW64, ROW64
#define ROW4096 ROW512, ROW512, ROW512, ROW512, ROW512, ROW512, ROW512, ROW512


std::complex<double> test_arr[2048][10] = {
    ROW512, ROW512, ROW512, ROW512
};

int main() {
}
```

The question is - what causes **g++** to abort compilation without even printing ANY error message?

Best regards (and thanks for the patience).

PS Inspired by @463035818_is_not_a_number i've tried to run **cplx_t** version using https://godbolt.org/ - results:

- GCC 10.4 - compiles well.
- GCC 12.2 - compilation failed, output:

```
g++: internal compiler error: Segmentation fault signal terminated program cc1plus
Please submit a full bug report, with preprocessed source (by using -freport-bug).
See <https://gcc.gnu.org/bugs/> for instructions.
Compiler returned: 4
```

- x86-64 clang 15.0.0 - compilation successful.
- x86-64 clang 3.0.0 - compilation fails with output:

```
<source>:22:16: error: variable has incomplete type 'cplx_t<double> [2048][10]'
cplx_t<double> test_arr[2048][10] = {
               ^
1 error generated.
Compiler returned: 1
```

Comment: `cplx_t<num_t>>` has unmatched `>` and what is `<re_0_0>, <im_0_0>` ?

Comment: this is not the code that produces no error. After adding some missing pieces and fixing 2 typos there are still many errors https://godbolt.org/z/YG7EYbKdG

Comment: please read about [mcve]. When `num_t` is just an alias for `double` then you need not use `num_t` and explain that its an alias for `double`, but you can use `double`. Maybe even `cplx_t` can be replaced by `std::complex`.

Comment: Sorry for that, i was writting in rush. "Code" was supposed to be a kind pseudocode just to present idea.

Comment: no idea why you get no output, but in any case the macros are wrong. Just consider the first level of expansion, `ROW8` is already `{ { 0.0, 0.0 }, {1.0 , 1.0} , ...{} }, { {} ,...{} }, ...`, then eventually for the initializer you add another pair of brackets around it

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number thank You for Your comment. To be honest i'm not sure why macros are wrong - ROW stands for single row (10 elements, second dimension of the array), while ROW8, ROW64 and so on should expand to 8, 64, ... rows separated with comas and whole thing is - in initialization - wrapped around curly braces.

Comment: hm, yes i misread the code

Comment: compiles ok here https://godbolt.org/z/KKjdd5EPE

Comment: As i stated - std::complex compiles fine, it is cplx_t template that causes the issue.
Please see here: https://godbolt.org/z/T8vcj45YT

Comment: ok now I can get a error message https://godbolt.org/z/W7cdvfqvY. An internal compiler error is always an internal error, a bug in the compiler. You can report it, or maybe it is already reported

Comment: Sorry for spam in comments - just want to add that marking constructors as *constexpr* allows compilation to pass; anyway i will try to report the bug.
Thank You for the support :)